# Using CMD How i create a new file that combines lines from from two other text files?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, merge, command-line, set

Here is what I am trying to achieve...

File1.txt
I love

File2.txt
Cake
Cheese
Money

File3.txt aka results.txt
I love Cake
I love Cheese
I love Money

I found the script below from another post, but it does not take into account the fact that one File only has one line while the other file has many lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(
< file2.txt (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
      set file2Line=
      set /P file2Line=
      set "file1Line=%%a"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion   
      echo(!file1Line!!file2Line!
      endlocal
   )
)
)>"result.txt"
pause
```

Thank you for the assist in advance

Comment: If the first file has just one line, just get it with `<file1.txt set /p "prefix="` before iterating over the second file with just `for /f "delims=" %%a in (file2.txt) do echo %prefix% %%a`

Comment: Would this be accurate below??

(
          < file1.txt set set /p "prefix="(
          for /F "delims=" %%a in (file2.txt) do %prefix% %%a
          set file2Line=
          set /P file2Line=
          set "file1Line=%%a"
          setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion   
          echo(!file1Line!!file2Line!
          endlocal
   )

Comment: no, that won't work at all. You need to read `file1` just once with the first code line from my previous comment. Then, iterate over `file2` with the second code line (just those two lines, nothing else is needed, not even delayed expansion or declaration of additional variables; Ok, `@echo off` certainly is helpful)

Comment: Hey Stephan, thanks for the Info, inclusion of your two lines, I followed this way

(
< File1.txt set /p "prefix="(
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (File2.txt) do echo %prefix% %%a >> Result.txt
)

Thanks for the assist mate!

Comment: `( for /F "delims=" %%a in (File2.txt) do echo %prefix% %%a) > Result.txt` makes it much faster (you won't notice it with your short example, but for big files, the difference is *huge*)

Comment: I considered that but only > would just rewrite the file while I need it to be appended.
The Script that I created takes Partial commands from two different files and create a new files in while the commands are inputted ">>Result.txt"

Afterwards, "Results.txt" is used initiated as cmd<Results >nul 2>&1 to process the commands themselves.

Comment: You get the same speed advantage with `(for ...)>>result.txt` - still the file gets opened, read to get to the end of the file,written to, and closed only once instead of doing it for each and every line.